# iptables TCP flags

Tags: tcp, iptables

I'm beginner with iptables and networking so please excuse me for such beginner questions.

I found on the Internet part of filtering malformed packets:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -A tcpchk -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN -m state --state NEW -j RETURN
```

But as far as I know, the first (new) packet should contain SYN flag and this rule will prevent new connections? Or am I misunderstanding this?

Also what will occur after applying the following rules?

```
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -A tcpchk -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST,ACK,PSH
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -A tcpchk -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST,ACK,URG
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -A tcpchk -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST,ACK,PSH,URG
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -A tcpchk -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,ACK,URG
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -A tcpchk -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ACK,URG
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -A tcpchk -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ACK,URG,FIN
```

If I'm right then there is no action? iptables will check above flags and just go to next rules, right?

Comment: superuser website is better to ask this

Comment: Look at the policy for `tcpchk` (check with `iptables -t tcpchk -L`). The question is neither dump nor dumb.

Comment: @ott-- any idea why the security.stackexchange people didn't want it? filtering malformed packets seems pretty security related.. the only flaw I see is the questioner seems like a newbie doing something quite technically advanced.

Comment: the common advice with iptables is experts (of which i'm not one), deal with specifics of tcp flags in iptables.. and regular techie people use something like  http://inai.de/documents/Perfect_Ruleset.pdf    you sound like a hobbyist and newbie, asking a theoretical question and maybe they don't know and don't care.

Comment: @begueradj it's quite a technical question, he'd be very lucky to get a good answer here. Though I guess if it's unsuitable for security.stackexchange.com then he hasn't got much choice

Comment: possible duplicate of [iptables TCP flags](http://superuser.com/questions/888686/iptables-tcp-flags)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd example has no action, so it does nothing except accumalate statistics.

```
iptables -xvn -L tcpchk
```

ALL SYN matches established connections, and kicks establish connection out of the tcpchk chain, and back to its parent chain presumably INPUT.  The **-j RETURN** return the packet to the parent.

The rule will not cause malfunction because it doesn't actually drop or reject anything.